# Cookies and subdomains for cookieless domains

Tags: http, cookies, web

I have set (I use PHP) my cookies' domain to be www.example.com - but will those cookies be sent back to the static.www.example.com? From what I've read already the answer is a depressing 'yes'.

The reason is that I'm trying to implement a static subdomain for CSS/images without resorting to buying an entire new domain (eg www.example-static.com)

Comment: Another thought - perhaps I could change the cookie-less domaain to be static-www.example.com (hyphen instead of dot)? Then the cookies from www.example.com wouldn't be sent to it?

Answer (score 1):

> From what I've read already the answer is a depressing 'yes'.

That's correct. If you set the cookie domain to `www.example.com` it will be sent to `*.www.example.com`.

Using `static-www.example.com` would work as expected and the cookie will not be sent to this subdomain.